# What is the best way to set font size for mobile, desktop, and print?

Tags: html, css, mobile, printing, font-size

I'm making a website and want the font size to be readable on mobile, desktop, and also when printed.
I find the default font size on my desktop looks good on desktop, but is way too small in mobile (and often I notice default fonts are way too big when printed). 
What's the best practice for setting a font size that is legible on mobile, desktop and print?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you can accomplish this one of several ways. Two concepts that come to mind would be to have a stylesheet that is for web which would control your desktop, tablet and mobile styling. You can then have a separate stylesheet that targets print which is a less complicated stylesheet. You can also use media queries to target media type also. A reference for how to accomplish this can be reference by visiting https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I was crossing my fingers that there might be a way that wouldn't require media queries or separate styles... but so far, ya this seems to be the only option.